# System of Equations Setup/Solution: Other Approaches?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations

I'm looking for solutions, $\vec{x}$, in $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ such that $||\vec{x}||_1$ is a minimum and $\vec{b}$ must have all even elements.

The A matrix is:
$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&1\\1&0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$

I stumbled across a puzzle in a game and set $\vec{b}$ to the zero vector for a solution but I'm curious: is there a way, other than brute force combinations, to find "the fewest lever pulls" (i.e. $||\vec{x}||_1$) solution?

**--EDIT--**

To expand on the idea, here's a more involved situation which may demonstrate what I'm looking to answer:

Imagine three concentric circles with a single marker on each and six levers which may be pulled down or pushed up to rotate them. When a lever is pulled/pushed(+/-), circles(s) will rotate (clockwise [-] and counterclockwise [+]) so that the markers will end in one of four positions- North, South, West, and East (modulo 4 {0, 2, 1, 3}, respectively). Consider the following A matrix...

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&-1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$

...where column 1 indicates that "pulling down (+) lever 1 will move the innermost circle counterclockwise one position", column 4 indicates "pulling down (+) lever 4 will rotate the innermost ring CW 1, middle ring CCW 1, and outermost ring CCW 1", and so on.

So, obviously, I'd be able to achieve any desired final position configuration by only using levers 1, 2, and 3. My questions:

1. What would be the problem setup to find the optimal lever pull combination and directions (i.e. fewest possible lever pulls/pushes total)?
2. How would I take into account the repeating positions and directions? For example, given a random initial configuration, say that I want the inner ring to point North (0), the middle to point West (1), and the outer to point East (3). Maybe the fastest way to East (position 3 in modulo 4) is actually "-1" in its movement (i.e. instead of rotating 3 times CCW, it is just 1 rotation CW). If that makes sense?

Comment: The determinant of the matrix is $1$. This means that for every $\vec b = 2 \vec k$ with $\vec k$ integer-valued vector there is a unique $\vec x$ that solves the equation. In particular, one solution is $\vec x=0$ for $\vec k=0$. Out of all possible solutions this is clearly the one where $||\vec x||$ is minimised. Is this what you were looking for? Given $\vec b$, there is only one $\vec x$ so there is nothing to minimise.

Comment: I see your problem talks about lever pulls. Is this problem intended to be in the integers modulo 2? It would be best if you also provided information about the problem you're trying to solve, just to set the context.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano I'll try my best to give some context. Imagine I have six lights in a row and below each light is a switch. Row 1 of A symbolizes, "if I flip the first switch, lights 1, 2, and 4 will change state (off-->on, on-->off)." Row 2 symbolizes, "if I flip the second switch, lights 1 and 2 will change state." The goal of the puzzle being to turn on all the lights. To take into account the initial state of the lights, the b vector ended up being the zero vector (i.e. I called evens ON, desired) minus some initial state vector (i.e. 6x1, zeros on, ones off). Hope that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

Over the field $\Bbb Z_2 $ (integers modulo $2$) the inverse of $A$ is well defined and:

$$A^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0&1\\1&0&1&1&0&1\\1&1&0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&1\\1&1&1&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix} $$
As such, if $b$ is required to be a vector of ones, $x = A^{-1}b$:
$$x = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which you can also check yourself since if I understand correctly, by flipping the first and last switch it is very evident that all lights will turn on. The method used is overkill in this case, but it very easily generalises (given enough computational power) for much more complicated problems. The solution is unique (so there is no minimising to do assuming you don't flip a switch twice!) and order doesn't matter.

Comment: So, in this case, the solution will be unique as A is full rank, invertible, well-defined, correct (assuming no double flips)? Suppose we now considered a more complicated system (integers modulo 4) and suppose there were, in fact, multiple possible solutions (say one could be accomplished in 3 "moves", the other 5). Would there be a way to directly find the 3 move answer and eliminate the other?

Comment: If there are more solutions, those must be of the form $A(x + y) = b$ and in particular $Ay = 0$. What this means is, the "extra moves" you are doing amount to flipping all the lights twice.

Comment: Minimising $x$ after finding all the solutions of the form $Ay = 0$ is a matter of subtracting. I'll be thinking about a general way to find this one solution.

Comment: I may update my post this evening to include the modulo 4 scenario, just for clarity. Seems to be a common game puzzle. :)

Comment: Added an update to main post; hopefully it makes sense.